# AWS ECS with Service discovery

Tags: docker, amazon-ecs, service-discovery

I'm trying to start ECS task (EC2 service, service type: REPLICA, number of task 1, min/max percent: 50/200) with Service discovery (its logstash docker image). If I don't enable 'Service discovery' it's starting without a problem, but when I enable it the task is created and then nothing happens. When I check the Deployments tab I get:

- Desired count: 1 (as set in service definition)
- Pending count: 0
- Running count: 0

no logs appear, no Events, no errors on ecs-agent on docker host. Any ideas?

Comment: There might be a problem pulling the docker image. How are you pulling your image ?

Comment: Check the "Events" tab under the service itself.